# nuxt 3 - where to customize SPA loading SVG?

Tags: nuxtjs3

When putting an app into non-ssr mode by suppling `ssr: false` in the config, there is the default green SVG "mountains" provided by nuxt. I know that there was a way to use some built in spinkit spinners in nuxt 2 but I cannot find an away to change / replace this SVG graphic with for example my logo. can someone point me in the right direction please?

Searched high and low but code seems built in somehow

Comment: Hi, please give a quick search next time: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76693564/8816585

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can customize the SPA loading screen template by calling the file name of the `HTML` file inside the `nuxt.config`. Ensure to disable SSR in order for it to work.

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  spaLoadingTemplate: 'spa-loading-template.html',
});
```

Create a file name `spa-loading-template.html` in the root directory. And that will be your loading screen template.

e.g.
`spa-loading-template.html`

```html
<style>
  .loading {
      background-color: #1e293b;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color:#15803d;
  }
  
  #spinner {
      width: 30px;
  }
  
  #spinner #sGD stop {
      stop-color: #16a34a;
  }
  
  #spinner .path-solid {
      stroke: #16a34a;
  }
  </style>
  <div class="loading">
          <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="spinner">
          <circle class="path-gradient" cx="32" cy="32" r="28" fill="none" stroke="url(#sGD)" stroke-width="8" />
          <path class="path-solid" d="M 32,4 A 28 28,0,0,0,32,60" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round"/>
          
          <defs>
              <linearGradient id="sGD" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="32" y1="0" x2="32" y2="64">
                  <stop stop-color="#000" offset="0.1" stop-opacity="0" class="stop1"></stop>
                  <stop stop-color="#000" offset=".9" stop-opacity="1" class="stop2"></stop>
              </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          
          <animateTransform
              values="0,0,0;360,0,0" 
              attributeName="transform" 
              type="rotate" 
              repeatCount="indefinite" 
              dur="750ms">
          </animateTransform>
          </svg>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

By following these setup, you should be able to see the custom loading screen.