# I want to get rid of this where nuxt3 starts for the first time

Tags: splash-screen, nuxt3

Whenever my nuxt3 project starts anew project, this [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ8Cg.png) pops up, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Version is
Nuxt 3.6.2 with Nitro 2.5.2

I searched the file nuxt.config.ts, and I looked it up on the nuxt3 official website, but I couldn't find it.

**It solved
[How do I disable Nuxt3 default loading indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693564/how-do-i-disable-nuxt3-default-loading-indicator)**

Answer (score 0):

It should get removed in production mode, try changing the env settings to production from dev.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved the problem by referring to this page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693564/how-do-i-disable-nuxt3-default-loading-indicator